# Netbeans 12.4, al cerrarlo, se reinicia

Tags: java, netbeans, windows10, plugin

Soy nueva en programación Java con Netbeans 12.4 y venía haciendo un proyecto,  después de corregir para que funcione el pluging nb-javac (me daba error cuando lo ejecutaba y lo mencionaba; vi que lo tenía desactivado y seguí consejos de esta comunidad), después de instalarlo, reinicié Netbeans (tengo Windows 10) y después cuando dejé de trabajar en él, quise salir y luego volvió a abrirse, y no dejó de hacerlo. No puedo cerrarlo y por más que cierro todos los proyectos, igual vuele a reiniciar. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

Comment: La forma ideal de plantear la pregunta, sería pegando como texto tu código para poder auditarlo y buscar los posibles errores. Un saludo

Comment: Es que tengo cerrados todos los proyectos en Netbeans y voy a File->Exit, se cierra la ventana de la aplicación y se abre de nuevo como si yo la abriera nuevamente. De todos modos, gracias por responder.